# Notification message for downvotes not displayed

Tags: support, down-votes, popups

Is the message box that is displayed when I downvote a question or answers disabled?

Currently I only get that blue messagebox on meta only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean the message box that says *Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved* then that box is only shown to lower-reputation users.

Quoting from [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/140890):

> It is shown on every downvote until you get to 2k.

You won't see the box when you have more than 2000 reputation points. Stack Exchange assumes you know by then that commenting on a downvote would be appreciated.